# No internet message webview fragment with pull do to refresh

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I searched here about "no internet message" for a webview, and i tried some codes, but no sucess. I have one WebView in fragment and i want to check if the device have internet or no. If yes, the webview will load. If no, another fragment will be load, and this new fragment will inflate a layout with the no internet message, and this layout will have a button to refresh (or a pull down to refresh). So, how can i implement the network check and refresh ?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(null == savedInstanceState) {
        // set you initial fragment object
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, InicioPagina.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

WebView Fragment

```
public class InicioPagina extends Fragment {

private ProgressBar prg;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
public WebView myWebView;

public static InicioPagina newInstance() {
    InicioPagina fragment = new InicioPagina();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.iniciopagina, container, false);
    prg = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
    myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inicio_pagina);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com.br/");

    //*Ativar JavaScript
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //*Forçar links para abrir no WebView ao invés do navegador
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    myWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            myWebView.reload();
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        prg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

content main xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context="br.com.example.example.MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

nointernet layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sem acesso a internet"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check internet availability by access to network state :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and you can check the internet by depend on this method :

```
 private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

ex :

```
if (!haveNetworkConnection()) {
        //inflate your fragment, THERE IS NO INTERNET!!
    }else {
       //you can reload or what ever you want now.
   }
```

Comment: I have a error: Cannot resolve method "getSystemService(java.lang.String)"

Comment: @TonyStarkus if you used in fragment, use `getActivity()

Comment: I'm using this method in the WebView fragment. i change "getSystemService" to "getActivity()", and now the error is in the next part: "(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);" is getting a error

Comment: When i turn internet off and i open the app, i get force close. In the "if" i just put "inflater.inflate(R.layout.nointernet, container, false);"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I use AlertDialogBox To show Internet Error and On try again button check Internet connection

```
 @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            //Clearing the WebView
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                webView.clearView();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }
            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);


        }
```